# Using angular 1 simple with express js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I have used node js with handlebars and now want to move towards the proper MEAN stack. I have learned angular1 and using it with single page node js apps.
But when it comes to express, after doing "express project-name" I start my server by "npm start" and in the "views" lies my html and angular code. How will by angular app there will interact or will run with my nodejs, I have scratched my head all over youtube videos and questions here but didn't find a satisfactory answer. What I want to work in angular is:-

```
$http.get('/users/signup',function(res){
console.log(res.data);
}
```

and in nodejs users.js route resides this:-

```
router.get('/signup',function(req,res,next){
res.send("req recieved here");
}
```

How will the req from angular be made to the server running using npm start??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

```
router.get('/signup',function(req,res){
    res.send("Any data");
});
```

Comment: It is already presend in my node app.js.
var users=require('./routes/users);
app.use('/users',users);
I want to understand how can I make from angular a req to the running server?

Comment: @AsimRaja See my answer

Comment: Share your js file contents